# Oracle query to display top 3 rows of the table without where condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to display top 3 rows of the table without where condition

Comment: Why do you need such a restriction?

Comment: What you mean by "top 3"? Records have no order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return the first 3 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROWNUM <= 3;
```

However, the results would be non-deterministic without an `ORDER BY`. So use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROWNUM <= 3 ORDER BY COLUMN1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this OK to be without *where condition* ..? :

```
select empno, deptno, ename 
 from
( select deptno, empno, ename, 
         row_number() over(order by empno desc) rn
    from emp ) e join      
   (
     select level lvl
       from dual 
    connect by level <= 3
   ) l on ( l.lvl = e.rn );

 EMPNO  DEPTNO  ENAME
 -----  ------  ------
 7934   10      MILLER
 7902   20      FORD
 7900   30      JAMES
```

where *emp* is classical *employee* table of Oracle.